# Manifolds and normal field

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Image we have a sufficiently differentiable manifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^p$ -of dimension $p-1$- and a normal field $\vec{n}$, meaning that for any $\vec{x} \in M$, we know that  $\vec{n}(x)$ has norm one and is orthogonal to each tangent vector at that point.
My question is: under what conditions can we write a point $\vec{u} \in \mathbb{R}^p$ as $\vec{u} = \alpha \vec{n}(\vec{x}) + \vec{x}$, where $\alpha$ is a real number and $\vec{x}$ is a point of the manifold. I can imagine this is not always uniquely possible (by looking at simple examples of curves).

Comment: You at least need to assume that $M$ has dimension$p-1$.

Comment: You're given a particular normal field? Or are you asking when you can represent $\vec u$ in that form for *some* normal vector $\vec n(\vec x)$?

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to write that M has dimension p-1 of course.

Comment: no, actually for some given field. Besides, I could always take a normal field corresponding to the tangent mapings resulting from some atlas right?